# why hello world text is not display?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am new in **Angular 2** .I saw this video 
https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-say-hello-world-to-angular-2

Now I want to make same demo on plunker I tried like that

http://plnkr.co/edit/uQa9ZIvb38iTMaXsecaC?p=preview

Please tell where I am doing wrong

// Code goes here

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector:'app',
  template:'<div>hello</div>'

})

class App{}


bootstrap(App)
```

Comment: Your <App> element is uppercase, your selector is lowercase.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/h4teylUvSwOZM6qaCtJY?p=preview still not working

Comment: Looks like you are not including the Angular /TS/System.js libraries in your HTML file ( in that plunkr)

Comment: from where i download this...? but in that video it is not include any thing

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi It would be helpful if you fix the plnkr.

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi pls provide plunker

Comment: @RoyiNamir Namir here a working plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xd0TbWO5deHB7xTjXibR?p=preview

Comment: Just one thing more - you should define your template string between backticks (` … `).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xd0TbWO5deHB7xTjXibR?p=preview)

Things that you should keep in mind:

- When you use `System.import('file.ts')`, you don't need to `<script src="file.ts">`
- Ensure you `System.config` with `transpiler: 'typescript'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which js file allows to write:  `'import {...}    from...'` ? ( in node it would be browserfy. but in browser?

Comment: the `import {} from ... ` syntax is ES6 and it's a syntax you can use in TypeScript (see https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html - section that starts with "import vs. window.angular")
So what allows you to do that is the `typescript.js` file

Comment: I see that I must use `system.js` also ?  ( is it mandatory ? )http://plnkr.co/edit/jh7EXgaVZZkfx0FTd7zl?p=preview

Comment: I think that you have to if you want to use TypeScript. Actually I realised that whilst the `import` is an ES6 syntax, System.js is what enables you to actually use it (as it is the underlying code that will load the module).
So in this case, System.js is used for 2 things - for importing AND transpiling TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your html code. here is official [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

**EDIT**

You will find working example here [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BPdzCZeXbyzQrgmLzO86?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Updated plunker. Also you have to place package files in standalone folder.